# What percentage of mobile browsers support CSS media queries?

Tags: mobile, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm developing a new website with mobile support, and I want to try using "responsive design"/"adaptive design"/CSS media queries. I'm wondering if there's a recent report of mobile browsers that support media queries. If not, what is a reasonable approximation?

Comment: All recent smartphones have support of MQ, at least with dimensions in px, not [rem](http://fvsch.com/code/bugs/rem-mediaquery/). None of of the very old mobiles support it. In between... So it depends of your needs, the country where live your users, etc

Answer (score 1):

I use this site all the time when I need to check out cross-browser support:
[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) This site says support for media queries (across all browsers) is at 78.37%

Support for mobile browsers is at 100%.

Comment: OP asked for support on **mobile** browsers. 78.37% is the overall support, desktop and mobile. It's 100% for the browsers followed by caniuse.com (Android 2.1, iOS3.2, Opera M*) but that doesn't include tons of other browsers (Windows *, old versions of BlackBerry Bold, Samsung bada - MQ are OK with bada 1.1 - ,etc). Support on desktop is primarily important if you're going Mobile First and also for taking care of different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

About 80%. You don't need to worry about Android, Opera Mini and iOS, but then there's the other 20% with Bada, old Blackberry phones, Windows Mobile... So you should add a polyfill life [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/) which will be helpfull for desktop browsers than don't support media queries like IE8 and bellow.

Answer (score 0):

About 87.14% support and 0.01% partial support. See more: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries